# bad_function_call when using lambda function on boost:heap

Tags: c++11, boost, lambda, functor

I want to create a heap data structure to be able to update the value .
but my simple code below throw an exception. why it gives the following:
`109 : 3 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_function_call' what():  bad_function_call`

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

#include <boost/heap/fibonacci_heap.hpp>

int main() {

    // Creating & Initializing a map of String & Ints
    std::map<int, vector<int> > mapOfWordCount = { { 1000, {0,1,10,8} },  { 10001, {1,5,99} },  { 1008, {7,4,1} } ,  { 109, {1,5,3} }};

    // Declaring the type of Predicate that accepts 2 pairs and return a bool
    typedef std::function<bool(std::pair<int, vector<int> > v1, std::pair<int, vector<int> > v2)> Comparator;

    // Defining a lambda function to compare two pairs. It will compare two pairs using second field
    Comparator compFunctor = 
        [](std::pair<int, vector<int> > elem1 ,std::pair<int, vector<int> > elem2)
        {
            return elem1.second.size() > elem2.second.size();
        };

    boost::heap::fibonacci_heap <std::pair<int, vector<int> >, boost::heap::compare<Comparator> > pq;
    typedef boost::heap::fibonacci_heap< std::pair<int, vector<int> >, boost::heap::compare<Comparator> >::handle_type handle_t;

    handle_t* tab_handle = new handle_t [mapOfWordCount.size()];
    unsigned iter(0);
    for( auto& element : mapOfWordCount) {
        tab_handle[iter++]=pq.push(element);
        std::cout << element.first << " : " << element.second.size() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have defined `compFunctor` - but you aren't actually using it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`std::bad_function_call` exception is caused (in this case) when calling a `std::function` that is empty.

I have made this work by making `Comparator` a functor.

```
struct Comparator
{
    bool operator()(std::pair<int, std::vector<int> > elem1, std::pair<int, std::vector<int> > elem2) const
    {
        return elem1.second.size() > elem2.second.size();
    }
};
```

This can then be used in the declarations of `pq` and `handle_t`.

**Output:**

```
109 : 3  
1000 : 4  
1008 : 3  
10001 : 3
```

See demo [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GOge4hyKnZa3LuWi).

You can figure out how to make it work with a lambda.
**Hint:** It involves using the lambda `compFunctor` as an argument for construction.

Comment: @ellie: you are welcome. You can mark this answer as accepted. See this link for additional info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers